# Linq to SQL and selecting user's projects in ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm new to LINQ to SQL and ASP.NET MVC. I have a project where I've added a *Project* table in the default identity model. Also I have added a *Project_ID* column to my AspNetRoles default table. So, my AspNetRoles table looks now like:

[image]

And my *Project* table looks like:

[image]

What I want to do:

1. After user loggs into the website it gets all the projects, he is taking part in.
2. The projects of users needs to be detected according to the Roles, that this user has.

It would not be difficult to compose an SQL query, but I want to use LINQ to SQL. To tell the truth I have no idea how to select projects, in which current user is taking part, basing on his roles. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 1):

This query should work, it will return project record:

```cs
var user_project = from role in AspNetRoles.Where(x => x.Id == UserRoleId)                 
                from project in Projects.Where(x => x.ID == role.Project_ID)
                select project;
// UserRoleId holds logged-in role id.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ to SQL your data context might have two classes AspNetRoles and Projects so your query looks like below:-

```
from t1 in Projects 
join t2 in AspNetRoles  on t1.ID equals t2.Project_ID
where (your conditions here....)
select new { t1.field2, t2.field3....}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't using a read-only context, if you have a `AspNetRoles` object and it is properly associated to `Project` in your dbml, it will have a member variable called `Projects`, which is a collection of all the `Projects` associated with the `AspNetRoles`, and can be called like any other collection:

```
AspNetRole user = (from x in context.AspNetRoles where x.ID == currentUserId select x).SingleOrDefault();
var allProjects = user.Projects;
```

You can also do the following statement to get them if you don't have a constructed object:

```
var userProjects = from x in context.Projects where userID == x.AspNetRoleID select x
//You haven't specified what the foreign key field name is
```

These both return `IEQueryables` as I recall, which use deferred execution so they may not actually contain values until you try to read through them, so if you want something you can edit before reading you'll need to use `toList()` or something similar.

I believe you can do this functionally with extension methods as well, IE:

```
var userProjects = context.Projects.Where(x => x.AspNetId == UserID);
```